# Should return throw new Error after second alert?

Tags: javascript

I'm curious on understanding functions. Is it bad to define a variable within a function before the conditional statement that deals with its parameters? This function should provide `throw new Error('Both arguments must be numbers!')` yet I'm receiving a syntax error.

```
function theRandomNumberCalc( upper, lower) {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (upper - lower) + 1 )) + 
  lower;
  if (isNaN(upper) || isNaN(lower)) {
   throw new Error('Both arguments must be numbers!');
  } else {
   return random;
  } 
};

alert(theRandomNumberCalc(6,5));
alert(theRandomNumberCalc('nine', 5));
```

Comment: In this line you have too  many closing brackets at the end

var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (upper - lower) + 1 )) + 

Should be var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (upper - lower) + 1 ) +

Comment: The syntax error you're getting has nothing to do with defining `random` before you need to. That said, in general, it's best to first validate your inputs (if you're going to validate them), and *then* use them, rather than using them and then validating them afterward.